# Using De Broglie matter wave hypothesis for expressing the wave funtion of a macroscopic body

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, foundations

Consider a body formed for $N$ identical particles, that moves freely at constant velocity through a region of space without interacting significantly with anything else. According to De Broglie's hypothesis each subatomic particle could be represented approximately as a plane wave of the form:

$$\psi_k(\boldsymbol{r},t) = G_i(\boldsymbol{r}) e^{i(\boldsymbol{k}_i\boldsymbol{r}-\omega_i t)}$$

where the linear momentum of particle $i$ is given by $\boldsymbol{p}_i = \hbar \boldsymbol{k}_i$ and $G_i(\boldsymbol{r})$ is a gaussian pre-factor that can be approximated by a constant in the relevant region and zero outside.

Because de macroscopic body is formed by $N$ particles the total momentum will be $\boldsymbol{P}= \sum_i \hbar\boldsymbol{k}_i$, then the De Broglie hypothesis seems to indicate that for the macroscopic body we have a wave function of the form:

$$\psi_B(\boldsymbol{r}_c;\boldsymbol{r}_i) = \bar{G}_B(\boldsymbol{r}_c, \boldsymbol{r}_i) e^{i[(\sum\boldsymbol{k}_i)\boldsymbol{r}_c-\Omega t]}$$.

where $\boldsymbol{r}_c$ are the coordinates of the center of mass $c$, and the $\boldsymbol{r}_i$ relative coordinates to $c$. But formally, this requires that it is possible to approximate a sum of plane waves as follows:

$$\sum_{j=1}^N G_j e^{ik_jx} = \bar{G} \exp\left( i x \sum_{j=1}^N k_i\right), \tag {*}$$

Is it possible to give an approximate mathematical justification that the formula $(*)$ is correct or possible? (even assuming that $\bar{G}(x)$ must be a slowly varying function in a certain region)

Comment: Is the "relevant region" just a region local to that particle, or to the whole solid? What is $\bar{G}_B$, is it just the product of all of the $G$? What is $\Omega$, is it just the sum of all $\omega_i$?

Comment: Also what is $r_c, r_i$? And, in the equation for the macroscopic body what is $r$?

Comment: I don't follow why there would be only one $r$ on the RHS of the equation for $\psi_B$. We are describing a multi-particle system

Comment: @doublefelix the vectors $\boldsymbol{r}_c$ refers to position of the center of mass, and the $\boldsymbol{r}_i$ are relative positions of all other particles with respect the center of mass.

Comment: I think in your equation labeled (*), on the LHS you want the $x$ to be $x_i$, no? This to me seems like the main difficulty in trying to arrive at your result. I am not sure if it is possible to remove the dependence on individual positions in the sum $\sum k_i x_i$.

Comment: What requirements do you have on $\bar{G}$? Do you expect that it should only consist of products of the individual $G_B$? If we let it be an arbitrary function of all coordinates, then it is trivially possible that something in the form (*) is possible, so without some requirements on $\bar{G}$ it is not possible to answer the question.

Comment: For sure $\bar{G}$ and $G_B$ are finite Fourier sum of terms with of the fom $\cos((k_1\pm k_2\pm \dots k_n)x)$ and $\sin((k_1\pm k_2\pm \dots k_n)x)$ if we want an exact formula, because $\bar{G} = e^{-i(k_1+\dots+k_N)x} \sum_{j=1}^N G_j e^{ik_jx}$. But if we choose a convenient approximation the form can be much simpler.